# Bash script for for copying all files in a directory and appending with filenameCopy

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I want to copy all files in a given directory, into the same directory, with a new name (something like: filenameCOPY).

I've tried a few different methods (globbing, cat, cp) but have yet to succeed. Here is where my code is currently at:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" = "1"]
then
    if test -d $1; then
        for file in $1/*; do
            //something
        done
    else
        echo "$1 is not a directory"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is something like this:

```
for file in "$1"/*; do
    cp -- "$file" "${file}COPY"
done;
```

right?

Comment: You should also double-quote `"$1"`. Any variable which contains a file name needs double quotes (and most others, too). So `for file in "$1"/*`

Comment: @tripleee -- quite right; I'll update my answer to reflect that :)

Comment: It's also a good idea to pass `--` as the first argument to `cp`, to prevent a filename from being interpreted as an option: `cp -- "$file" "${file}COPY"`.

Comment: That does the job, thank you! I should have looked closer at cp.

Comment: @ruakh -- that's a new one to me, I must admit, but clearly sound; thanks!